# Listen for new event after transition is finished

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, transition

I want to add a transition that pushes my main content down when the twitter bootstrap collapse menu is active via the toggle button.

But unlike the collapse menu transition, if I double click the toggle button quickly, my main content elements do not finish their initial transition and instead use the transition for going back up.

In conclusion, if I toggle the collapse menu before my main content transition is finished, my content will go up and hide behind the Bootstrap collapse menu.

In the CSS, the important parts are the two transitions at the very bottom.

```js
var icon = document.getElementsByClassName("icon-bars");
var pushDown = document.getElementById("push");

//icon[0].addEventListener("mouseenter", highlight)
//icon[0].addEventListener("mouseleave", highlightNone);

/*
function highlight() {
  listOfIcons = document.querySelectorAll(".icon-bar");
  for(var i=0; i<listOfIcons.length; i++) {
    listOfIcons[i].classList.add("icon-bar-light");
  }
}

function highlightNone() {
  var listOfIcons = document.querySelectorAll(".icon-bar");
  for(var i=0; i<listOfIcons.length; i++) {
    listOfIcons[i].classList.remove("icon-bar-light");
  }
}
*/

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(icon[0]).click(function(){
    if($(pushDown).hasClass("push")){
      pushDown.className = "pushUp";
    }
    else{
      pushDown.className = "push";
    }
  })
});
```

```css
form {
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
}

input, textarea {
    border: 3px solid #f47909;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

input:focus, textarea:focus {
    outline: none;
    border: 3px solid #f2a25a;
}

label {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

span {
    display: block;
}

textarea {
    max-height: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    max-width: 300px;
}


/*rest same as index.css*/

*{
    font-family: 'futura';
}

.navvy {
    border-radius: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    height: 70px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar .navbar-nav {
        display: inline-block;
        float: none;
    }
    li{
      padding-right: 30px;
      font-size: 19px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar-collapse {
      margin-top: 15px;
      background-color: #FAFAFA;
    }
    li {
      font-size: 17px;
    }
}

.icon-bar {
  background-color: #337ab7;
}

.icon-bar-light {
  background-color: #23527C;
}

#li-back:hover {
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.navbar-brand {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #1d78c6;
}

#footer {
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  border-top: 2px dotted #8bc771;
  text-align: center;
}

#description {
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.push{
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  transform: translate(0px, 160px);
}

.pushUp{
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  transform: translate(0px, 0px);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>VirusFun</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Great+Vibes" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/contacts.css" type="text/css">

</head>
<body>
  <div class="introPic">

  </div>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top navvy">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed icon-bars" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Virus Fun</a>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-center" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" role="navigation">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a id="li-back" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a id="li-back" href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
          <li><a id="li-back" href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a id="li-back" href="contacts.html">Contacts</a></li>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>

  <div id="push" class="">
    <!--The blurb -->
    <p id="description">Ask whatever you want!</p>

    <!-- The body -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <form action="https://formspree.io/jackgong48@gmail.com"
        method="POST">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
            <label id="name">
              <span>Your Name</span>
              <input tabindex="1" placeholder="John Smith" type="text" name="name">
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
            <label id="email">
              <span>Your Email</span>
              <input tabindex="2" placeholder="johnsmith@gmail.com" type="email" name="Sender">
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>

        <label>
          <span>Your Message</span>
            <textarea tabindex="3" name="message"></textarea>
        </label>
        <div class="send">
            <input tabindex="4" type="submit" value="Send">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <footer id="footer">
        <p>© 2017 VIRUS FUN ALL RIGHTS RESERVED</p>
    </footer>
  </div>

    <!--need this code to be declared before javascript-->
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="/javascript/javascript.js"></script>

    <script src="jquery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion https://jsfiddle.net/ye4s17n8/3/. 
The key moment here is the class of the navbar "in", which is applied only if menu is shown and also class "collapsing", which is applied during the animation of the menu.

**HTML**

```
<div id="push" class="push">
```

**CSS**

```
.push      { transition: transform 0.5s;}
.push.up   { transform: translate(0px, 0px); }
.push.down { transform: translate(0px, 160px); }
```

**JS**

```
var $toggle = $('.navbar-toggle');
var $push = $('#push');
var $navbar = $('.navbar-collapse');

$toggle.on('click', function(){
  if ($navbar.hasClass('collapsing')) {
    return false;
  }
  if ($navbar.hasClass('in')) {
    $push.removeClass('down').addClass('up');
  } else {
    $push.removeClass('up').addClass('down');
  }
});
```